what kind of ssl certificate do i need?
I want to create a proxy server using Node.js and the http-proxy library, allowing me to browse any website with Firefox and all the traffic will go through the proxy. I am having trouble with SSL certificates. What certs do I need and how do I generate them?

Use certbot and you should be ok

Heres the code we use in ZAP :) It might give you some clues: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/network/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/addon/network/internal/cert/CertificateUtils.java#L88

Use Let's Encrypt with your Node.js proxy, install Certbot on your server and run sudo certbot certonly --standalone to generate the SSL certificate. Certbot will handle getting the certificate and private key files for you. Once done, point your Node.js proxy to these files (usually stored in /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain/). You'll also need to configure Firefox to use the proxy, and set up automatic renewal with Certbot to keep your cert valid.
